# WUSA Error code 3010

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-update

I'm trying to remotely install a windows update .msu file on a remote computer.  I ran the following command

```
psexec \\com-479 -s wusa \\"commonshare\updates\windows6.1-KB4088875-x86.msu" /quiet /norestart
```

And it seems to exit with error code 3010.  I can't find any information about that code.

Specifically, the error is:

```
PsExec.exe : Connecting to local system...
At line:1 char:7
+ psexec <<<<  \\com-479 -s wusa \\"commonshare\updates\windows6.1-KB4088875-x86.msu"
 /quiet /norestart
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Connecting to local system...:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Starting PSEXESVC service on local system...Connecting with PsExec service on com-479...Starting wusa on com-479...
wusa exited on com-479 with error code 3010.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found something helpful [here](https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/152125/installation-or-a-scripted-install-retur.html):

> What does error 3010 mean?
>
> 3010
>
> The requested operation is successful. Changes will not be effective
> until the system is rebooted.
>
> ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_REQUIRED
>
> This isn’t really an error but is just
> a code stating that the operation completed successfully and requires
> a reboot to become effective. What Switch is causing the problem? The
> problematic switches in many of the scripted install process are:/q,
> /q:a, /z, /r:n.   These switches either suppress the prompt that tells
> the user that they need to reboot the computer for the install to
> finish or force the install without a reboot.